# Is it possible to get the name of the object being instantiated, from within the constructor?

Tags: c#, reflection

Is there any way, using reflection, ConstructorInfo or System.Runtime.CompilerServices or something else, to get the variable name of the object being created?

```
Example:

public class MyObject
{
    public MyObject()
    {
       // Should print "Creating funnyName"
       Debug.Writeline("Creating {0}", MagicGetNameMethod());
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public MyObject funnyName = null;
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        funnyName = new MyObject();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope. But why you need it? If it's somehow important pass it to the constructor.

Comment: The object executes Actions passed to the constructor. It is called by many methods.  I am timing how long the actions take to execute. The variable name is how I know what action is being executed.

And I'm not free to just change the constructor. I can get decent information from Environment. StackTrace, (calling method and line number) but it still requires looking at the code to see exactly what action was being performed.

Comment: You probably can hack up something with [callerargumentexpressionattribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerargumentexpressionattribute?view=net-6.0) but it I assume you'd have to stick with factory methods like `CreateMyObject(out MyType result, [CallerArgumentExpression("result")] string message = null)`.

Comment: @Bruce: Wrap your action in a class `MyAction` which has properties `Name` and `Action` and pass that to the constructor. Even better than a `Name` was an enum `ActionType`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I would love to do that but I'm not at liberty to change the class, constructor signature, etc. We're trying to add this performance logging with minimal impact to existing code.

Comment: why it should be happen like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the file path, line number and method name of the caller, which is probably more useful for timing info:

The following will print something like `Creating MyMethod@c:\source\MyProgram.cs:15`.

```
public class MyObject
{
    public MyObject(
         [CallerMemberName]string caller = null, 
         [CallerFilePathAttribute] string path = null, 
         [CallerLineNumber]int lineNumber = 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Creating {0}", $"{caller}@{path}:{lineNumber}");
        System.Reflection.
        
        MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public MyObject funnyName = null;
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        funnyName = new MyObject();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually doing that now. The problem is, this is going into a log with thousands of entries. While knowing the calling method and source line will take me to where the information is, that is a manual operation which would have to be done for thousands of log events.

Comment: Can you explain why knowing the variable name is _more_ useful? It's less unique, and less descriptive than using `[CallerMemberXXX]` attributes... (for example, lots of methods might use the same variable name, making it kind of useless for your stated purpose)

Comment: Sure, imagine you have a class that executes some Action asynchronously. And it is called multiple places for the actions DoThis(), DoThat(), DoSomething(), DoSomethingElse().

If all I know it was called in mysource.cs on line 256, I have to go to the source file to determine that DoSomethingElse() was the method called. From the log file, line 256 is only marginally helpful.

And I see your point about the variable name but in my actual use case, the variable names are all very descriptive actions e.g. PrintReport() or SaveMemberInfo() etc.